# Axios multiple upload with vue and multer

Tags: express, vuejs2, axios, multer

I need to do multiples files uploads with vue.js 2.0 and multer .

I've followed this doc for multiple uploads : 
https://serversideup.net/uploading-files-vuejs-axios/

This is my vue template :

```
<label>Files
    <input name="streamfile" type="file" id="files" ref="files" multiple @change="handleFileUploads" />
</label>
<a v-on:click="submitFiles" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</a>
```

My axios query is the same as in the doc .

This is my multer code :

```
var upload = multer({ dest: "uploads/" });
app.post("/files", upload.array("streamfile", 50), function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.files); // []
  console.log(req.body);
  var file = req.files;
  console.log(file);
  res.end();
});
```

I 'm getting this error :

```
MulterError: Unexpected field
    at wrappedFileFilter (C:\UwAmp\www\vue-starter-webpack-cli-4-node\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (C:\UwAmp\www\vue-starter-webpack-cli-4-node\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
    at Busboy.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Busboy.emit (C:\UwAmp\www\vue-starter-webpack-cli-4-node\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
    at PartStream.<anonymous> (C:\UwAmp\www\vue-starter-webpack-cli-4-node\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
    at PartStream.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (C:\UwAmp\www\vue-starter-webpack-cli-4-node\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)
    at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at HeaderParser._finish (C:\UwAmp\www\vue-starter-webpack-cli-4-node\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:68:8)
    at SBMH.<anonymous> (C:\UwAmp\www\vue-starter-webpack-cli-4-node\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:40:12)
```

The single upload is working well, i've removed it to avoid any conflict .

The files gets correctly imported in the front end  :

```
File { name: "Builder.png", lastModified: 1571932750271, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 821185, type: "image/png" }
Uploadfiles.vue:52
File { name: "classic-music.png", lastModified: 1573131217357, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 4073, type: "image/png" }
Uploadfiles.vue:52
File { name: "dossier.pdf", lastModified: 1571842341052, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 320949, type: "application/pdf" }
Uploadfiles.vue:52
```

***Edit :***

As long as I send only one file, it works :

**Vue.js :**

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file',this.files[0]);
axios.post(this.server + 'files',
                    formData, {
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                        }
                    }
                ).then(function (response) {
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                });
```

**Node.js :**

```
var upload = multer({ dest: "uploads/" });

    app.post("/files", upload.array("file", 10), function(req, res, err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      req.files.forEach(function(file) {
        console.log(file);
      });
    });
```

As long as I'm trying to send an array, it won't work, and throws **MulterError: Unexpected field** !

```
  formData.append(file,this.files[0]);
  formData.append(file,this.files[1]);
```

**Resolved : In case somebody has the problem , it was annoying !:**

This is my vue.js 2.0 code now , **Please notice 'Content-Type': 'undefined'**:

```
var formData = new FormData(); 
for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    var file = this.files[i];
    formData.append('file', file);
}
axios.post(this.server + 'files',
    formData, {
        headers: { crossdomain: true,
            'Content-Type': 'undefined'
        }
    }
).then(function (response) {
})
.catch(function (error) {
});
```

and my node.js code :

```
var storageFiles = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./uploads/files");
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    let ext = file.originalname.substring(
      file.originalname.lastIndexOf("."),
      file.originalname.length
    );
    cb(null, file.originalname + "-" + Date.now() + ext);
  }
});

var uploadFiles = multer({ storage: storageFiles });


app.post("/files", uploadFiles.array("file", 10), function(req, res, err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Please don't add the answer inside the question. Chances are users won't read the question in its entirety (since it's fairly long) and won't notice you answered it inside the question itself. Please add a proper answer and accept it when the grace period ends.